# Two different design in Drupal website

Tags: 7

My website has two designs and I not sure which one is better. I am thinking upload both of them.

Here is my question: Is drupal able to let 50% of the user see design A and the rest is able to view design B. After one month later, I am able to see a report which one is better.

Comment: hook_custom_theme()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ThemeKey](https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey)

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching
>   rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current
>   path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other
>   properties. It can also be easily extended to support additional
>   properties exposed by other modules.

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I know is:

### [Switchtheme](https://www.drupal.org/project/switchtheme)

> Adds a block to allow users to switch between enabled themes.
>
> Themes can be given 'user friendly' names and access can be controlled
> by user role.
>
> Switchtheme provides optional support for [Browscap](https://www.drupal.org/project/browscap) module to switch
> themes based on the browser of a visitor.

Comment: Didn't know about this one. Any criteria/suggestions about how to decide between this module and Themekey? Or should it post this as a new (official) question?

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens idk the answer to that, so a new Q will be educational.